# Jsp El inside an EL

Tags: jsp, el

I have a variable  x which is equal to "oxford".

```
${Place['name_oxford']} will give result as england.
```

But if I try `${Place['name_'+x]}` I get error.

How to resolve this ?

Comment: I have a loop of all schools each time x takes different school names

Comment: [This is the same question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19819475/1031945) you have asked. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19829081/1031945)

Answer (score 1):

The `+` operator doesn't concatenate strings in `EL`, you'll have to use `String.concat` method.

You could try something like this:

```
${Place['name_'.concat(x)]}
```

Comment: Or use the EL provided += operator. It is a few characters less.

Comment: @user35690 What's your `EL` version?