# Concatenate of a string within a loop in JSP

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, jstl, jsp-tags

`${x}="mit"`

`${Place['name_mit']}` will give result as US.

But if I try `${Place['name_'+x]}` I get error.

How to resolve this ?

Comment: Have you tried concatenating the string in a variable beforehand and using it as a key?

Comment: I cant do that, these school names are coming from db, for each school I am performing the same action.

Comment: I mean like this.  `${x}="name_mit"` then ${Place[x]}

Comment: how to concatinate before hand ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it fails to compile as `+` operator is not used for string concatination (before EL 3.0, Java EE 7).
Just use `concat`

```
${Place['name_'.concat(x)]}
```

---

From Expression Language 3.0,
It is valid to use `+` operator for concatenation of two strings.

```
${Place['name_'+x]}  //valid as of EL 3.0
```

From [EL 3.0 Specs](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr341/index.html)

**String Concatenation Operator**

To evaluate

```
A += B
```

- Coerce A and B to String.
- Return the concatenated string of A and B.

Comment: I get this messsage The function concat must be used with a prefix when a default namespace is not specified

Comment: @user35690 : It is working fine for me. For error see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8340659/1031945).

Comment: I am using apache tomcat, thanks for he link. but I think its a differenet issue

Comment: @user35690 : Post the stack trace in the question. specify web server with name, version, java ee version.

Comment: currently using jsp 1.2
  <tlibversion>1.0</tlibversion>
  <jspversion>1.2</jspversion>
  <shortname>app</shortname>
  <uri>/WEB-INF/app.tld</uri>

Comment: @user35690 : You need to have JSP 2.2 to use this function. See above mentioned link in comments.

Comment: I cant change the version, is there other way I can get this running ?
Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You can't concatenate the map key inline like that.  This worked for me:

```
<%
    Map<String, String> things = ImmutableMap.of("thing1", "a", "thing2", "b", "thing3", "c");
    pageContext.setAttribute("things", things);
    for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
        String key = "thing" + i;
        pageContext.setAttribute("key", key);

%>
    <c:out value="${key}"/>: <c:out value="${things[key]}"/> <br>
<%
    }
%>
```

Obviously, without context from your use case, I had to cobble together an appropriate page context state on my own.  Substitute as necessary.

Comment: Way too complicated. Just use the += operator in the EL.

Comment: @Mark, can you elaborate? Please note that most of the complexity in my answer was to get myself into the situation the OP was asking about. The "answer" portion is only two lines.